# Magento - Currency changes on all pages but home

Tags: magento, caching

I'm testing the currency selector on my store htt://limamelao.com.br and all is going well, all pages work correctly when changing the currency, but when you change the currency on the front page nothing updates! The prices show the same in Brazilian Reais.

I'm using a cache plugin called GT Speed and also Varnish Cache. Would this be a plugin problem?

Any ideas on how to change this?

UPDATE - 
This is the code for the popular products:

```
<?php $avail = false; ?>
<?php
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addViewsCount()
        ->setOrder('views_count', 'desc') // most best sellers on top
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)//enabled
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)//catalog, search
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
        // deprecated 
        // Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);


 $_productCollection->setPage(1, 40);


?>  


        <div class="popular_box">
            <div class="tital">
            <div class="hr"><h1>+ Vendidos</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div id="popular-product-carousel" class="ui-carousel module ui-touchCarousel ui-touchCarousel-horizontal ui-touchCarousel-items-3 ui-touchCarousel-rows-1">
            <div class="carousel-mask">
                 <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
            <ul id="new-product-collation" class="ui-draggable">
            <?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : $avail = true;?>

            <li class="arrivals_price_box item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

                    <div class="view view-first">


                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(248,270) ?>" width="231" height="260"  alt="arrivals price 4" /></a>
                            <div class="sale">
                                <?php $cdate = date('Y-m-d');  //echo 'frpm:-'.$_product->special_from_date.'----';echo "to:-".$_product->special_to_date.'--';
                                    $a= 0;
                                    if($_product->special_from_date != null && $_product->special_to_date == "")
                                    {
                                    if( $cdate >= $_product->special_from_date)
                                    {
                                        $a = 1; 
                                    }
                                    }
                                    if($_product->special_from_date != "" && $_product->special_to_date != "")
                                    {
                                    if($cdate >= $_product->special_from_date && $cdate <= $_product->special_to_date)
                                    {
                                    $a = 1; 
                                    }
                                    }
                                    if($a == 1){ ?>
                                       <div class="sale_img"></div>
                                    <?php } 
                                    ?>

                                <?php if($this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) != null): ?>
                                <div class="star_img"><?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?></div>
                                 <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mask">
                            <h3 class="product-popular-name">
                            <?php 
                                $productName = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
                                if(strlen($productName) > 25) {
                                    $productName = substr($productName,0,25)."...";
                                }
                            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $productName; ?></a>    
                            </h3>               
                                <div class="price-popular-box">
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></div>


                                <div class="product_btn_popular">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" class="btn_view btn_add_bag btn_add_bag_position info" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho">Adicionar ao Carrinho</a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="product_btn last">
                                     <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="btn_view btn_view_product btn_view_product_1 info" title="Adicionar a Lista de Desejo"></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="btn_view btn_view_product btn_view_product_2 info" title="Ver Detalhes"></a>
                                </div>  
                            </div>

                    </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul></div></div>
        </div>

        <?php
        if($avail == true)
        {
        ?>
        <?php
        }?>
```

Comment: How do you display product on Home Page?

Comment: I have a widget for the popular products that I updated on the post with the code. Thanks